# SELinux settings for Paypal

Tags: magento2.4, paypal

When using SElinux I need to set

/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1

as per: https://community.magento.com/t5/Payments-PayPal/PayPal-NVP-CURL-connection-error-7-vendor-magento-module-paypal/td-p/448795

But this setting gets lost if I restart the server. How can I make this persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use cron to achieve this, first open a crontab using the below command.

```
crontab -e
```

Then, add the below content in your crontab, it will execute the below command when server reboot.

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

**sleep 60** is used to run the setsebool command after 60 seconds. You can adjust sleep time whatever time you want.

**Another method:**

1. [By using custom service.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355661/176196)